# Laravel Data-Mapping

Tags: php, laravel, csv, import, data-mapping

I need to import a XLSX/CSV file to my Laravel app and I want to create a table to the same fields and titles in database which means creating fields for every single field from the importing file to the database dynamically without any implements in the code again

Answer (score 0):

You can load a file using :

```
use File;

public function loadFile()
{
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('path/to/filename'));
}
```

Once it is loaded you can work the $csv just like array. Since .csv is a comma seperated values, you can loop through the data just like in multidimensional array

Comment: this is just for csv what about the excel sheet

Comment: I need to do this for excel sheet too